# How to reload in jquery datatable when callback draw?

Tags: jquery, datatables, settimeout

I have a jquery DataTable is server-side processing mode .
How to add setTimeout function when server side callback [like this](http://www.cscc.edu/_resources/app-data/datatables/extensions/scroller/examples/server-side_processing.html)

my code as below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "ordering": true,
     "order": [[1, 'desc']],//default
      "lengthMenu": [
        [50, 100, 1000],
        [50, 100, 1000]
      ],
    
     "ajax": function ( data, callback, settings ) {
        url: "process.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {
       start: "<?php echo $start; ?>",
       end: "<?php echo $start; ?>"
          },

        setTimeout( function () {
            callback( {
                draw: data.draw,
                data: aaData,
                recordsTotal: data.recordsTotal,
                recordsFiltered: data.recordsFiltered
            } );
        }, 50 );
    },
     
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":'details-control',
            "orderable":false,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "time"},
    { "data": "message","orderable": false}
        
    ],
    "dom": 'frtiS',
    "scrollY": 600,
    "scroller": {
        
         "loadingIndicator": true
    },
    "deferRender":    true

} );
```

Obviously this doesn't work ,
Can someone point me out the correct way to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `setTimeout()`. It was used in the example to emulate server-side response and add delay.

If used, Scroller extension will pull new data from the server automatically.

See corrected `ajax` option below:

```
"ajax": {
   "url": "process.php",
   "type": "POST",
   "data": {
      "start": "<?php echo $start; ?>",
      "end": "<?php echo $start; ?>"
   }
},
```